# How to configure tools in kendo editor in angular using directive

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

when I'm using standard jquery, I can configure the toolbar buttons this way:

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
        tools: [bold,...
```

but how do  do it when using angular js and the code for initializing the editor is just this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <textarea kendo-editor ng-model="data.html"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML put:

```html
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <textarea kendo-editor ng-model="data.html" k-options="myOptions></textarea>
</div>
```

and then in your controller add something like:

```html
$scope.myOptions= {
     tools: ["bold", "italic", "insertUnorderedList"]
}
```

see here for more details http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/all-tools